# Difference between USP and IEEE rounding

Tags: numeric-precision

I am trying to understand the difference between different rounding methods: Our application offers two different types of rounding:

- IEEE
- USP (GMP) rounding. http://www.usp.org/sites/default/files/usp_pdf/EN/USPNF/USP34-NF29General%20Notices.pdf

In our unit tests, they seem to do the same thing for the cases being tested. However, I haven't found anyone in the office who can explain what is meant when selecting rounding mode of IEEE

Comment: What?! You don't already have unit tests to validate the difference between the two rounding methods?  That seems like the easiest place to check and verify their operation.

Comment: @GlenH7 I'll be sure to add them now :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding), IEEE 754 specifies round to even when the next digit is a 5, while the paper you cite says that a digit of 5 means add one to the preceding digit.

Comment: I was just typing an answer, that is the actual behavior in our application. However, where in that document does that say that it should round to even? Doesn't it say that there are 5 different types of tie-breakers?

Comment: @JuanMendes Under Round to even: *"This is the default rounding mode used in IEEE 754 computing functions and operators."*

Answer (score 1):

I haven't fully figured it out. However, I know enough to keep working. IEEE rounding has 5 different modes. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point#Rounding_rules

In our application, we are using C#'s default method, `Math.round()` which uses `MidpointRounding.ToEven`, that is, 4.5 rounds to 4 and 5.5 rounds to 6. So when our applications says IEEE rounding, they mean  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even